# laravel foreach in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called **folder** and I have the following attributes:

- id_folder
- name
- sub_dossier_id **(not a foreign key)**

---

- id_folder : 1
- name : folder1
- sub_dossier_id :1

### When id_folder = sub_dossier_id ====> it's a folder

---

- id_folder : 2
- name : folder2
- sub_dossier_id :2

### When id_folder = sub_dossier_id ====> it's a folder

- id_folder : 3
- name : folder3
- sub_dossier_id :1

### When id_folder != sub_dossier_id ====> it's a sub folder and her folder parent is a folder1

- id_folder : 4
- name : folder4
- sub_dossier_id :2

### When id_folder != sub_dossier_id ====> it's a sub folder and her folder is a is a folder2

I tried with this in controller :

```
$sub_folders = Folder::whereRaw('id_folder!=sub_dossier_id')->get();
$folders = Folder::whereRaw('id_folder=sub_dossier_id')->get();
return view('/',['sub_folders'=>$sub_folders, 'folders'=>$folders]);
```

**view.balde.php**

```
@foreach($folders as $folder)  
    <ul>
        {{ $folder->id_folder }}

        @foreach($sub_folders as $sub_folder) 

            <li>{{ $sub_folder->sub_dossier_id }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

**But is show me all folder in tag ul**

Comment: Can you show us the output? Looks to me like it's going to do something like: folder/sub/sub/folder/sub/sub.

Comment: how do you expect the output ?

Comment: Be more clear please. What's the problem and the current result

Answer (score 0):

**Relations**

First of all, you have to assign relations to your Folder Model.

```
public function subfolders() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Folder', 'sub_dossier_id', 'folder_id');
}
```

In this way you'll be able to retrieve a collection of subfolders in the following way

```
$folder->subfolders
```

In order to simplify your works with Eloquent I suggest you to name your IDs just id and the subfolders IDs as folder_id

**loop and view**

In your controller, the one that retrieve the list of folders, you have to add a where like "subfolder=0" in order to retrieve just the main level folders.

Then you are quite fine with what you did.

```
<ul>
@foreach($folders as $folder)
    <li>{$folder->name}</li>
    @if($folder->subfolders)
      <ul>
        @foreach($folders as $folder)
            <li>{$folder->name}</li>
       @endforeach
       </ul>
    @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```

*I'm answering you from mobile phone, not so comfortable in writing code...*